# присвоить кнопке или классу число jquery или javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как присвоить кнопке или классу число например 100 ,нажимаю на кнопку где присвоено число 100 а потом на нажимаю на другую кнопку и это число 100 присваивается другой кнопки , кто что может предложить или поправить меня

Comment: Предлагаю поправить вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, исходя из сложного вопроса, выглядит это в этом духе

Жмём первую кнопку, получаем 100
Жмём вторую и присваиваем значение первой

```js
first = document.querySelector('#first');
second = document.querySelector('#second');

get = 0;

first.onclick = function() {
  get = this.value;
}

second.onclick = function() {
  this.value = get;
}
```

```html
<input id='first' type='button' value='100'>
<input id='second' type='button' value='0'>
```

Comment: А если кнопок много в html коде как выбрать нужный ?

Comment: @Timur3250, указать каждому `input` `class` с перебором или свой оригинальный `id`

Comment: @Timur3250, обновил пример с `id`

Comment: Вижу ,Понял тебя.

Comment: Код который ты написал так и надо просто вставить  в js документ ?

Comment: @Timur3250, да прям так. Главное подключать его в конце html, после body

Comment: @Timur3250, если вопрос удовлетворительный, отметь как верный галкой

Comment: Отметил..............

Comment: @Timur3250, красава

Comment: Обращайся))))))

Comment: Если таких кнопок 4 , одна с 0 остальные 100 ,200,300 , как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку с 0 эти числа взятые с трех кнопок прибавлялись к кнопке с 0? Или мне лучше новый вопрос задать ?

Comment: @Timur3250, лучше новый, подробный и грамотно составленый